# Showing progress or "loading" when opening a C# app that relies on a slow SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an application that uses an MSSQL connection for data. However, due to reasons far beyond my control, the connection is beyond slow when it first runs my query. Because of this, the application crashes due to a timeout. I'm still trying to figure out how to catch that part (any help is, of course, appreciated!)...in the meantime, how can I display the main form with some kind of loading bar to indicate that the application is actually doing something? Right now it doesn't display the form unless the SQL query is successful.

Comment: What kind of application is this..a web app, console app, windows forms app?

Comment: Sorry - It's a Windows forms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the timeout, you might have to increase the ConnectionTimeout property of your SqlConnection and/or the CommandTimeout property of your SqlCommand.  Both are set to 30 seconds by default.

As for showing progress, keep in mind that you can only report progress that you can measure.  If you can't actually measure progress then your best bet may be to display a ProgressBar with its Style set to Marquee.  The question is whether you want to display the ProgressBar on a splash screen before the main form loads or on a dialogue or the main form itself after the main form loads.  Answer that and I can provide further information.

Comment: I hadn't considered using a splash screen - that's a good idea! My application only talks to the SQL server at launch, so that would work well - just a "loading data..." kind of status.

I've read about CommandTimeout but haven't figured out where it belongs in my generated code. I created my DSN with the wizard. This is my first time using an MSSQL data connection for a desktop application, so I'm new to this.

Comment: Wherever you create the SqlCommand is where you set the CommandTimeout property.  You might use initialiser syntax, e.g. `var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection) {CommandTimeout = 60};`, or you might set it on the next line with a conventional property assignment.  Regardless, you set it before executing the command.